# What does an operation in Azure Application Insights corresponds to?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

How does Azure Application Insights assigns the same operation ID to various events?

Comment: Can you provide more details please? What is the operation id and events you're referring to?

Comment: Post question with details.

Comment: There is something called an operation in AI that links different telemetric data by assigning an ID to them. I just want to have a thorough definition  of what an operation is and how does AI decides to link those events together.

Answer (score 2):

I assume we are talking about Web SDK where ApplicationInsights uses http module to track requests, exceptions and dependencies. On request begin in the module unique id is saved in the HttpContext. When new items are tracked in the scope of the same request HttpContext.Current is checked; if it is not null and has id, it is used as operation id. The obvious limitation of this approach is that it will not be prorogated to async operations since HttpContext.Current would be null.

For async operations you can use operations API that would require code modifications from your side. Documentation about operations API: https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/app-insights-api-custom-events-metrics/#operation-context